# What is the seed when I don't specify one

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can I retrieve the randomly selected seed value if I write the following?

```
var randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
```

I looked at the suggested answers and they do not explain how to get the seed that .Net chose.

Comment: AFAIK, by default Random uses time ticks count: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs

Comment: It is mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer. "The default Random constructor uses Environment.TickCount as the seed". But you want to get this value. Not possible.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thank you for pointing that out. Intuitively I would assert that the seed must be available somewhere but I accept the verdict of SO on my question.

Comment: Source code is the highest authority. You can study the code of `Random` class, given in the link in the first comment here. In the class constructor the seed is broken down into 3 components, `inext`, `inextp`, and `SeedArray`, which are not even accessible from outside.